# serialize date attributes

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, active-model-serializers

I am using active_model_serializers and ember.js. One of my models has a date attribute. In rails date attributes are serialized in the format of "YYYY-MM-DD".

The problem; when ember-data de-serializes the date using the javascript Date constructor it assumes an "incorrect" timezone.

*Incorrect is not the best word but it is incorrect because I want it to default to the current timezone. [DS.Model date attribute parses date (YYYY-MM-DD) incorrectly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12523373/ds-model-date-attribute-parses-date-yyyy-mm-dd-incorrectly)

I am thinking the active_model_serializer should take the date attribute and convert it to iso8601 format.

```
 Object.date.to_time_in_current_zone.iso8601
```

Is there a way to tell active_model_serializers how to serialize all date objects? Or should I be fixing the timezone issue in javascript?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is my current solution but I really feel it should be possible to define how date objects get serialized globally.

```
class InvoiceSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :customer_id, :balance

  def attributes
    hash = super
    hash['date'] = object.date.to_time_in_current_zone.iso8601 if object.date
    hash
  end
end
```

UPDATE

My preferred solution now is to monkey patch the `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone.as_json` method.

```
#config/initializers/time.rb
module ActiveSupport
  class TimeWithZone
    def as_json(options = nil)
      time.iso8601
    end
  end
end

class InvoiceSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :customer_id, :balance, :date
end
```

Comment: You can also add an arbitrary attribute: `attributes :id, :customer_id, :balance, :date` and then just implement `def date` instead of messing with the whole attributes hash.

Answer (score 3):

In the last version of ActiveSupport (4.2) Dates are under iso8601 format. You don't need anymore Monkey Patch. You can configure the output format

```
#config/initializers/time.rb
ActiveSupport::JSON::Encoding.use_standard_json_time_format = true # iso8601 format
ActiveSupport::JSON::Encoding.time_precision = 3 # for millisecondes
```

[See the doc](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-2-stable/activesupport/lib/active_support/time_with_zone.rb#L155)